# Cant remove spaces by CSS

Tags: html, css

Please check this
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/hp-designjet-750c-24-refurbished-plotter-1

in the quick overview, it shows some text with big spaces.

But if you see this:
http://www.theprinterdepo.com/printer-bundles/plotters-bundles

It doesnt show the spaces.

I havent been able to find how to remove those spaces even though its the same html code.

```
<p><span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: large;"><strong>SAVE 5% ON ALL BUNDLE ITEMS TOGETHER.</strong></span></p>
<p>1 x Black Ink (51645A)<br/>
1 x Cyan Ink (51644C)<br/>
1 x Magenta Ink (51644M)<br/>
1 x Yellow Ink (51644Y)<br/>
<strong>2 x 36" 20 bond paper (C3859A)</strong><br/>
1 X Network Card<br/>
1 Year Extended Warranty
```

I tried with LI, with P, and with BR but none of them work.

THe

Comment: I cheked the second link with firebug and it shows that there are 2 <br/> after each color.The fist link has only one <br/> after everycolor.so i guess that the reasson ...

Comment: and one mpre thing at the first link the css file has this in it '.products-list .desc {
    line-height: 1.35;
}'that means its affecting the space between the text sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by assigning the line-height of your div class "std" to be .67

```
.std {line-height:.67;}
```

An easier approach to fixing the spacing issue would be to remove the extra `<br>` in the code.

Answer (score 4):

The space is because you have double `<br />` between entries in the HTML code.

Comment: actually in the html of the CMS its not there.

Comment: Yes, what I'm telling you - it's not a CSS issue. Look at the your CMS documentation.

Comment: They're in the source HTML of the page, and they're certainly in the DOM. So yeah, they're there. And they're why there's huge spaces.

Answer (score 2):

The extra new lines on the first page are caused by extra `<br>` tags. If you're editing the HTML and only seeing one `<br>` tag in a row, then you're editing the wrong file or wrong part of the file.

***Note:** If you're 100% positive it's the only file, then your content management system is adding in the extra `<br>` tags by itself. If this is the case, then possibly removing the raw new lines (not `<br>`, but the new line in the html source) may fix the issue.*